# How do I wrap text in the edit text box for a gridview control in asp using vb?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I'm using VS2019 and VB on an aspx page. I have a gridview that has Edit enabled.

[image]

When you click Edit, the text appears, however all of the text appears on a single line and does not wrap (comments column).

[image]

I've used the ControlStyle to increase the size of the text box (400x240), but the text is still centered in the textbox and does not wrap.

I don't see options for wrap text or alignment.

How do I do this?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdgoals" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="DS1" Height="225px" Width="1001px" BorderColor="#003960" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" DataKeyNames="goalid" EmptyDataText="No goals found." Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Overline="False" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Strikeout="False" ForeColor="#00AD86" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AllowSorting="True" style="margin-right: 21px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="goalid" HeaderText="goalid" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="goalid" Visible="False" />
                <asp:CommandField EditText="EDIT" ShowEditButton="True" ShowHeader="True">
                    <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#003960" />
                <ItemStyle Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#006EAA" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="#003960" Width="20px" />
                </asp:CommandField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="goaltext" HeaderText="Goal" SortExpression="goaltext" ReadOnly="True" >
                    <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#003960" />
                    <ItemStyle BorderColor="#003960" Width="250px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" DataField="type" HeaderText="Type" ReadOnly="True" >
                <ItemStyle Width="70px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="progress" HeaderText="Progress %" SortExpression="progress" >
                    <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#003960" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="#003960" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="20px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="comments" HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="comments" ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
                    <ControlStyle Height="400px" Width="240px" />
                    <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#003960" />
                    <ItemStyle BorderColor="#003960" Width="250px" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="approved" HeaderText="Approved" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="approved" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#006EAA" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

I've tried to use code like this but EditItemTemplate that I found online but get a message that its not supported.

'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of using a bound field, you can drop in a plane jane text box.

So, say in an area outside of the GV, drag + drop in a text box.

Set the text mode =

So, your text box will look like this:

```
       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="112px"
            TextMode="MultiLine" Width="282px">
        </asp:TextBox>
```

So, it will create a nice larger text box.

[image]

Now, in the GV, remove the one databound text box, and use what is called a template field, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" SortExpression="HotelName" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="80px"
                    Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="80px"
                    TextMode="MultiLine" Width="282px"
                    Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'>
                </asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So, note how we added both the template, and what we want for the "edit template". We use a text box - not a label.

So, now we will see/have this effect:

[image]

So, you can drop in a text box, text mode = multi-line, and you should then have a nice text edit area.